# Is it OK to mix string parsing while learning reg ex?

Tags: regex

I'm performing some regular expression exercises in Python 2.7.3, on Windows 7.  Some of these exercises have me looking for similar patterns on the same line.  For example, I want to use regex to capture name1 and name2...

```
<XML tag><more tags>[name1]</XML tag><XML2 tag>[name2]<XML2 tag></more tags>
```

Would it be "cheating" or "missing the point" if I used any string parsing to capture name2?  I feel like using regex the correct way alone should be able to capture both of those names, but string parsing is what I've always been familiar with.

An analogy would be like someone studying recursion in C++, but using a While loop.  Recursion should NOT have any While loops (although of course it may be part of some other grand design).

Comment: Can you supply some example code? If I understand right, I think the point of the exercises is to help you learn how regular expressions work, and so all of the exercises should be do-able using regexes alone; if you don't know how, then isn't the point of the exercise to help you to learn how by figuring it out?

Comment: It's good that you understand that there are sometimes better tools than regex for a given task (in this case, it might be a DOM parser). However, using them in a regex exercise is definitely missing the point…

Answer (score 2):

Good question!  Many beginners come into it believing they should be able do everything with one regex match.  After all, people are always saying how powerful regexes are, and what you're trying to do is so simple...

But no, the regex is responsible for finding the next match, that's all.  Retrieving the substring that it matched, or finding multiple matches, or performing substitutions, that's all external to the act of matching the regex.  That's why languages provide methods like Python's `findall()` and `sub()`; to do the kind of "string parsing" operations you're talking about, so you don't have to.

It occurred to me a while back that the process of mastering regexes is one of learning everything you can't do with them, and why not.  Understanding which parts of the regex matching operation are performed by the regex engine, and which parts are the responsibility of the enclosing language or tool, is a good start.